# Total is not adding up at the end of C++ program

Tags: c++

Hello I am working on an assignment. I have spent numerous hours and cannot figure out why at the end of my program the "Total Commission" and "Total Due" are not adding up. I am a beginner so anything that could lead me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**original code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

const double PC_BASE_SALES = 6000.00, //PC is Personal Computers
             PC_COMMISSION = 0.12,
             PRINTER_BASE_SALES = 2500.00,
             PRINTER_COMMISSION = 0.10,
             ACCESSORIE_BASE_SALES = 2000.00,
             ACCESSORIE_COMMISSION = 0.10,
             MAINTENANCE_BASE_SALES = 1500.00,
             MAINTENANCE_COMMISSION = 0.06;

double       baseSalary = 0.00,
             pcSales = 0.00,
             printerSales = 0.00,
             accessorieSales = 0.00,
             maintenanceSales = 0.00,
             totalCommission = 0.00,
             totalDue = 0.00,
             noCommission = 0.00,
             pcCommission = baseSalary * PC_COMMISSION,
             printerCommission = baseSalary * PRINTER_COMMISSION,
             accessorieCommission =  baseSalary * ACCESSORIE_COMMISSION,
             maintenanceCommission = baseSalary * MAINTENANCE_COMMISSION;

int          idNumber; //salesman identification number

do
{
cout << "Please Enter Salesman Identification or -999 to Terminate ";
cin >> idNumber;

if (idNumber == -999)
    return 0;
else

cout << "Please Enter Salesman Base Salary\t\t\t  ";
cin >> baseSalary;

cout << "Please Enter Personal Computer Sales\t\t\t  ";
cin >> pcSales;

cout << "Please Enter Printer Sales\t\t\t\t  ";
cin >> printerSales;

cout << "Please Enter Accessories Sales\t\t\t\t   ";
cin >> accessorieSales;

cout << "Please Enter Maintenance Sales\t\t\t\t  ";
cin >> maintenanceSales;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;

cout << "\t\t\t  My Computer Company\n ";
cout << endl;
cout << "\t\t\t Commission Statement\n ";
cout << endl;
cout << "\t\t\t  Salesman Number " << idNumber << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "\t\t   ********************************\n";
cout << endl;

cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);

cout << left << setw(20) << "Product";
cout << right << setw(20) << "Sales Amount";
cout << right << setw(20) << "Commission";
cout << "\n" << endl;

cout << left << setw(20) << "Personal Computers";
cout << right << setw(20) << pcSales;

while (pcSales > PC_BASE_SALES)
    {
        double pcCommission = baseSalary * PC_COMMISSION;
        cout << right << setw(20) << pcCommission;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        pcCommission += totalCommission;
        break;
    }
    while (pcSales < PC_BASE_SALES)
    {
    cout << right << setw(20) << noCommission;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    break;
    }

cout << left << setw(20) << "Printers";
cout << right << setw(20) << printerSales;
    while (printerSales > PRINTER_BASE_SALES)
    {
        double printerCommission = baseSalary * PRINTER_COMMISSION;
        cout << right << setw(20) << printerCommission;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        printerCommission += totalCommission;
        break;
    }
    while (printerSales < PRINTER_BASE_SALES)
    {
        cout << right << setw(20) << noCommission;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        break;
    }

cout << left << setw(20) << "Accessories";
cout << right << setw(20) << accessorieSales;
    while (accessorieSales > ACCESSORIE_BASE_SALES)
    {
        double accessorieCommission =  baseSalary * ACCESSORIE_COMMISSION;
        cout << right << setw(20) << accessorieCommission;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        accessorieCommission += totalCommission;
        break;
    }
    while (accessorieSales < ACCESSORIE_BASE_SALES)
    {
    cout << right << setw(20) << noCommission;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    break;
    }

cout << left << setw(20) << "Maintenance";
cout << right << setw(20) << maintenanceSales;
    while (maintenanceSales > MAINTENANCE_BASE_SALES)
    {
        double maintenanceCommission = baseSalary * MAINTENANCE_COMMISSION;
        cout << right << setw(20) << maintenanceCommission;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        maintenanceCommission += totalCommission;
        break;
    }
    while (maintenanceSales < MAINTENANCE_BASE_SALES)
    {
    cout << right << setw(20) << noCommission;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    break;
    }

cout << endl;

      totalCommission =  pcCommission + printerCommission + accessorieCommission +   
      maintenanceCommission;
      totalDue = baseSalary + totalCommission;

cout << left << setw(20) << "Total Commission";
cout << right << setw(40) << totalCommission;
cout << "\n" << endl;

      cout << left << setw(20) << "Base Pay";
cout << right << setw(40) << baseSalary;
cout << "\n" << endl;

cout << left << setw(20) << "Total Due";
cout << right << setw(40) << totalDue;
cout << "\n" << endl;

    } while ( idNumber != -999);

system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

**updated code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

const double PC_BASE_SALES = 6000.00, //PC is Personal Computers
             PC_COMMISSION = 0.12,
             PRINTER_BASE_SALES = 2500.00,
             PRINTER_COMMISSION = 0.10,
             ACCESSORIE_BASE_SALES = 2000.00,
             ACCESSORIE_COMMISSION = 0.10,
             MAINTENANCE_BASE_SALES = 1500.00,
             MAINTENANCE_COMMISSION = 0.06;

double       baseSalary = 0.00,
             pcSales = 0.00,
             printerSales = 0.00,
             accessorieSales = 0.00,
             maintenanceSales = 0.00,
             totalCommission = 0.00,
             totalDue = 0.00,
             noCommission = 0.00,
             pcCommission = baseSalary * PC_COMMISSION,
             printerCommission = baseSalary * PRINTER_COMMISSION,
             accessorieCommission =  baseSalary * ACCESSORIE_COMMISSION,
             maintenanceCommission = baseSalary * MAINTENANCE_COMMISSION;

int          idNumber; //salesman identification number

do
{
cout << "Please Enter Salesman Identification or -999 to Terminate ";
cin >> idNumber;

if (idNumber == -999)
    return 0;
else

cout << "Please Enter Salesman Base Salary\t\t\t  ";
cin >> baseSalary;

cout << "Please Enter Personal Computer Sales\t\t\t  ";
cin >> pcSales;

cout << "Please Enter Printer Sales\t\t\t\t  ";
cin >> printerSales;

cout << "Please Enter Accessories Sales\t\t\t\t   ";
cin >> accessorieSales;

cout << "Please Enter Maintenance Sales\t\t\t\t  ";
cin >> maintenanceSales;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;

cout << "\t\t\t  My Computer Company\n ";
cout << endl;
cout << "\t\t\t Commission Statement\n ";
cout << endl;
cout << "\t\t\t  Salesman Number " << idNumber << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "\t\t   ********************************\n";
cout << endl;

cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);

cout << left << setw(20) << "Product";
cout << right << setw(20) << "Sales Amount";
cout << right << setw(20) << "Commission";
cout << "\n" << endl;

cout << left << setw(20) << "Personal Computers";
cout << right << setw(20) << pcSales;

if (pcSales > PC_BASE_SALES)
    {
        double pcCommission = baseSalary * PC_COMMISSION;
        cout << right << setw(20) << pcCommission;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        totalCommission += pcCommission;
    }
if (pcSales < PC_BASE_SALES)
    {
    cout << right << setw(20) << noCommission;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    }

cout << left << setw(20) << "Printers";
cout << right << setw(20) << printerSales;

if (printerSales > PRINTER_BASE_SALES)
    {
        double printerCommission = baseSalary * PRINTER_COMMISSION;
        cout << right << setw(20) << printerCommission;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        totalCommission += printerCommission;
    }
if (printerSales < PRINTER_BASE_SALES)
    {
        cout << right << setw(20) << noCommission;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
    }

cout << left << setw(20) << "Accessories";
cout << right << setw(20) << accessorieSales;

if (accessorieSales > ACCESSORIE_BASE_SALES)
    {
        double accessorieCommission =  baseSalary * ACCESSORIE_COMMISSION;
        cout << right << setw(20) << accessorieCommission;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        totalCommission += accessorieCommission;
    }
if (accessorieSales < ACCESSORIE_BASE_SALES)
    {
    cout << right << setw(20) << noCommission;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    }

cout << left << setw(20) << "Maintenance";
cout << right << setw(20) << maintenanceSales;
if (maintenanceSales > MAINTENANCE_BASE_SALES)
    {
        double maintenanceCommission = baseSalary * MAINTENANCE_COMMISSION;
        cout << right << setw(20) << maintenanceCommission;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        totalCommission += maintenanceCommission;
    }
if (maintenanceSales < MAINTENANCE_BASE_SALES)
    {
    cout << right << setw(20) << noCommission;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    }

cout << endl;

totalCommission =  pcCommission + printerCommission + accessorieCommission + maintenanceCommission;
totalDue = baseSalary + totalCommission;

cout << left << setw(20) << "Total Commission";
cout << right << setw(40) << totalCommission;
cout << "\n" << endl;

cout << left << setw(20) << "Base Pay";
cout << right << setw(40) << baseSalary;
cout << "\n" << endl;

cout << left << setw(20) << "Total Due";
cout << right << setw(40) << totalDue;
cout << "\n" << endl;

    } while ( idNumber != -999);

system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: That is a huge piece of code, narrow it down to an http://sscce.org/. Also, *explicitly* mention what output you were expecting and what output you're receiving, do not simply say "are not adding up".

Comment: In the first printers loop, are you sure about the condition? Either you will never enter the loop or you have an infinite loop. Same with the accessories and maintenance loops.

Comment: Store all monetary values as cents in integer variables and do integer arithmetic.

Comment: I also recommend you read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: You will need a '{' after the first `else` and a matching '}' at the end of the content.

Comment: To get help from stack overflow you really need to take a few steps yourself: 1. Focus the problem down to as small a working piece of code as possible. In your case, reduce the number of inputs to the fewest possible where you still get unexepcted output. 2. Walk it through the debugger and note where there values go wrong. 3. Show the expected output and explain **clearly** what goes wrong. These are the normal steps any programmer should take anyway and will probably help YOU fix the problem on your own. Without them, it looks like some lazy ass posted their class project for us to fix.

Comment: This was my first time posting here. So I appreciate the tips. However your assumption this is just a "lazy ass" trying to get their homework fixed for them is incorrect. When I run the debugger and the program runs fine and there is nothing on the error list how do I walk through the debugger? That would be helpful and constructive. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Are you intentionally writing code for a obfuscated C++ competition?

This (as an example of several similar ones):

```
while (printerSales > PRINTER_BASE_SALES)
{
    double printerCommission = baseSalary * PRINTER_COMMISSION;
    cout << right << setw(20) << printerCommission;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    printerCommission += totalCommission;
    break;
}
```

is exactly the same as :

```
if (printerSales > PRINTER_BASE_SALES)
{
    double printerCommission = baseSalary * PRINTER_COMMISSION;
    cout << right << setw(20) << printerCommission;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    printerCommission += totalCommission;
}
```

since the `break` is unconditional inside the loop, and thus makes the loop only ever run once. This is possibly what you wanted in the first place.

Also, since `printerCommission` is a local variable inside the loop, this will not do anything useful.

```
    printerCommission += totalCommission;
```

did you mean:

```
    totalCommission += printerCommission;
```

Also, as the comments say, using `double` or `float` to calculate money will eventually go wrong, because floating point values will sometimes round off incorrectly. For example, in binary floating point representation, the values 0.1, 0.2 and 0.6 and 0.7 would be 0.099999999999999, 0.199999999999999, 0.59999999999999 and 0.699999999999 respectively. It's the same as trying to express 1/3 in decimals, 0.333333333 - no matter how many digits are used, it can not be "exactly 1/3". If you do enough math using such values, it will end up "wrong". But you should get approximately the right value, give or take a cent or whatever the small part of the currency is called.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did make all the changes and the code is cleaner. However the output is still incorrect. For Total Commission it is still 0.00 instead of adding all the commission totals. Also the Total Due is just showing the base salary of 1500 without adding the Total Commission. Thanks.

Comment: And what does the code look like now? To be able to answer, you should add this as a second section of code in your question, as it's hard for someone else to see what my answer (or anyone else's answer/comment) is referring to if you replace the code in your question.

Comment: Hi Mats, I did update the code in this question with your suggestions. I explained what I did in the edit summary. This is the first thing I have ever posted here so I am new. Also this is only my third week learning programming. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: So, you have just calculated all the partial commissions and added it into `totalCommision`, and then you do `totalCommission =  pcCommission + printerCommission + accessorieCommission + maintenanceCommission;` - which doesn't make sense, since those variables are not the ones you used inside the `if`-statements (used to be `while`). If you remove the duplicate variables, and leave the local ones in the if-statements, it will be much better.

Comment: Finally! Thank you so much Mats for taking the time to help me figure out what I was doing wrong. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an issue I found:

An `else` statement without `{` and `}` will only execute the next statement:

```
do
{
    cout << "Please Enter Salesman Identification or -999 to Terminate ";
    cin >> idNumber;

    if (idNumber == -999)
        return 0;
    else // <---  This else will cause only the next line to be executed
         //       since there is no '{' following it.

    cout << "Please Enter Salesman Base Salary\t\t\t  ";
    cin >> baseSalary;
```

Have you single stepped through the code with a debugger?